# Insert into a new table with values from session state and another table

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to insert from a procdure into a new table like the below 
The unit_id is from a table called lms_units and it has a FK to lms_qualifications called qualification_id
The table will have 1 Trainer with 1 qualification and all the units that go with it

```
insert into LMS_TRAINER_QUALI_UNITS
(
lms_trainer_quali_units_id,
Trainer_id,
Qualification_id,
unit_id
)
Values
(
lms_trainer_quali_units_id_seq.nextval,
:P2_Trainer_id,
:P6_qualification_id,
Unit_id --- this will have many values 
)
```

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE lms_qualifications (
       Qualification_id, Title, Code
) AS
SELECT 33450, 'Lifter', 123 FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE LMS_UNITS ( 
       Unit_id, Qualification_id, description
) AS
SELECT 69052, 33450, 'Elective' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 69053, 33450, 'core' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 69054, 33450, 'core' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 69055, 33450, 'Elective' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 69056, 33450, 'Elective' FROM DUAL;
```

Expected  on `LMS_TRAINER_QUALI_UNITS`

```
+----------------------------+------------+------------------+---------+
| lms_trainer_quali_units_id | Trainer_id | Qualification_id | unit_id |       
+----------------------------+------------+------------------+---------+
| 50001                      |       4500 | 33450            | 69052   |
| 50002                      |       4500 | 33450            | 69053   |       
| 50003                      |       4500 | 33450            | 69054   |
| 50004                      |       4500 | 33450            | 69055   |       
| 50005                      |       4500 | 33450            | 69056   |
+----------------------------+------------+------------------+---------+
```

Comment: It is nice that you want to do that... but what is your question?

Comment: How do I get the values to insert for the many unit_id's

Comment: Are you asking how to implement a `NESTED TABLE`? Or how to normalise your database (in which case `UNIT_ID` does not go in the same table but into a separate table with a foreign key to `LMS_TRAINER_QUALI_UNITS_ID`)? Or how to enter multiple `UNIT_ID`s each with their own unique key from the sequence? Or something else? Please provide a [MCVE] including your table structures,examples of your input data and your expected results for that data.

Comment: lms_qualifications
Qualification_id           Title            Code
33450        Lifter        123

LMS_UNITS 
Unit_id   Qualification_id        description 
69052  33450    Elective
69053  33450    core
69054  33450    core
69055  33450    Elective
69056  33450    Elective


Expected  on LMS_TRAINER_QUALI_UNITS
lms_trainer_quali_units_id - Trainer_id - Qualification_id -             unit_id
50001               4500  33450    69052
50002         4500  33450    69053
50003        4500  33450    69054
50004        4500  33450    69055
50005       4500  33450    69056

Comment: Sorry I messed up the table formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` to copy values from one table to another:

```
insert into LMS_TRAINER_QUALI_UNITS (
  lms_trainer_quali_units_id,
  Trainer_id,
  Qualification_id,
  unit_id
)
SELECT lms_trainer_quali_units_id_seq.nextval,
       :P2_Trainer_id,
       Qualification_id,
       Unit_id
FROM   LMS_UNITS
WHERE  Qualification_id = :P6_qualification_id
```